# SDK 49 vs SDK48 and Expo Go versions difference

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using same simulator for both projects, one project with sdk49 and other sdk48.
The 49 needs to have updated version of Expo Go app on the simulator. But when i run sdk48 project it asks the same even tho the Expo Go has been updated by sdk49.

When starting sdk48 and i have updated Expo Go i can just type n in terminal and it works but this is annoying to type every time. And i dont know if this is an issue that i'm using more latest version of Expo Go with older SDK and that for some reason SDK say i need to update.

Is there away of starting a project and specifying what simulator to use per proejct? So then i could have 2 simulator configurations for each project?